# Create individual plots for all values in a variable

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, tidyverse, line

My dataset has 3 columns: high school name, year, and percent enrolled in college, and it includes 104 high schools across 8 years.

| school | chrt_grad | enrolled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alba | 2012 | 0.486 |
| Alba | 2013 | 0.593 |
| Alba | 2014 | 0.588 |
| Alba | 2015 | 0.588 |
| Alba | 2016 | 0.547 |
| Alba | 2017 | 0.613 |
| Alba | 2018 | 0.622 |
| Alba | 2019 | 0.599 |
| Alba | 2020 | 0.614 |
| City | 2012 | 0.588 |
| City | 2013 | 0.613 |

and so on...

I'm trying to produce 104 individual line plots--one for each school. I started by creating a single line plot showing every school:

```
ggplot(nsc_enroll,
         mapping = aes(x = chrt_grad, y = enrolled, group = school)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

How can I create an individual plot for each of the 104 schools without having to filter for each school name over and over again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I suppose that where you write chrt_grad it's the same as year or do you have another variable?
Anyway, it's not the point.
As you may know, +facet could do multiple plots, but not individually as I know.
I have a similar situation and what I would do, at least it works for me, is to:

1. Spread (if you know gather/spread) variable school
2. For loop to plot each column.

I am not at home now if you need it I can text the code.

Recently I saw some new dplyr tidyverse code using nest_by. It's very interesting although I haven't tried it yet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `facet_wrap` with `ggplot`,

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg))+
        geom_point() +
        facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

[image]

In your case you would `facet_wrap(~school)`, but it will produce a huge amount of plots.